# flash card flip animation in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to build a view/page in my WP7 app where users could swipe from left to right or right to left to see different flash cards (say a very large number in total ~ 1000+) and if user taps on it the flash card flips horizontally to show its back side (and vice versa).

I am not able to figure out which controls I should use on WP7. It was quite easy to do in iPhone app as UIScrollView would allow 1000+ views inside it and default flip animation would allow each view to flip with animation very nicely. I'd like to achieve same thing in WP7 but being new to it can't figure out how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

if your using WP7.1 Beta 2, you could try building it as a hybrid Game application and using some of the features from XNA.

XNA is Completely Game oriented so it has alot more graphical features.

[great Place to Start](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-1-Fundamentals.aspx)

that should help you with the integration and learn how both work together, im currently developing an app the same way and it works wonderfully. :)

Comment: Perhaps that's the only way left, to learn XNA and do animations by hand. However, I found at least you can use ListBox to scroll horizontally. I am still exploring that option as scrolling via ListBox is very continuous. One flick from left to right could makes you go past several items in the list. Flipping is another thing which right now I have no clue -- except this pointer to XNA -- to try out.